# Summary date alloted wise

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I want to know sales done by a each salesperson in different areas.
There are many areas, and many salespersons.

They are allotted to different areas periodically.
There sales figures and time of sales are recorded.

Area (table)

```
id name
1 A
2 B
3 G
4 D
and many more
```

Salesman (table)

```
id name
1 X
2 Y
3 Z
....and many more
```

datetime_alloted (table)

```
id area salesman datetime
1  3    2        1st Feb 2020 9:00am
2  2    2        2nd Feb 2020 9:00am
3  4    1        3rd Feb 2020 11:00am
4  3    1        3rd Feb 2020 11:00am
5  1    3        5th Feb 2020 10:00am
6  2    1        5th Feb 2020 10:00am
7  4    3        6th Feb 2020 10:00am
```

Sales (table)

```
id area     sales datetime
1  3        25   1st feb 2020 1:00pm
2  2        18   3rd Feb 2020 11:am
3  3        30   2nd Feb 2020 2:00pm
4  4        24   3rd Feb 2020 2:00pm
5  4        12   3rd Feb 2020.4:00pm
6  3        20   5th Feb 2020 2:00pm
7  1        24   4th Feb.2020.11:30am
8  1        38   6th Feb 2020.3:00pm
```

So my output for each salesman:

```
salesman area.    1st Feb.     2nd Feb.   3rd Feb 5th Feb.   6th Feb
   2     3         25           30                          38
   2     2                                18                        
   1     4                                30          
   1     3                                36      20
   3     1                                        24
```

Basically, salesman wise/area wise/daywise sales by each salesman.

Even if it's not in pivot form. it will help.

EDIT: An area can only be allotted to one salesman. When an area is reallotted, it is assumed that the previous salesperson ceases to be allotted to that area

Comment: Do you want that output for one specific month or all months (and dates) that are are present in the `datetime_alloted` table?

Comment: Between a range of dates

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason for downvote. Will help in future.
Thank You

Comment: I am thinking, if I have an extra field on the Sales table which saves the salesman's id. This can make the query simple.